# How to fix NFS V3 + TCP mount failing with 'Can't read superblock' error soon after an unmount?

Tags: linux, nfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

Using NFS V3 and TCP!, portmapper is running. Not using iptables.

Following are the options used:

```
rw,noatime,v3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,hard,intr,nolock,proto=udp,udp,timeo=11,retrans=5
```

If I wait for some 20 minutes, then the mount happens.

I'm running RHEL-4.6, 64-bit, kernel version 2.6.9.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post more information? What happens when you ping from your NFS client box to the NFS server? How about a traceroute? Does DNS resolve a FQDN for the NFS server?

Comment: Yes, the ping is successful with response time 0.150 ms, the filer is addressed by a FQDN and not an ip address, traceroute succeeds with just one intermediate hop.

Comment: I am just throwing this in but I am sure you know that RHEL4 is end of regular lifecycle.